# Generating random variables from the multivariate t-distribution

Tags: r

I wanted to generate random variables from a multivariate t distribution in R.  i am using the `mvtnorm` package which has the command `rmvt` for generating  random variables from the multivariate t-distribution.  Now my question is about the syntax of the function and being able to manipulate it to do what I want.  The function requires the following

```
rmvt(n, sigma = diag(2), df = 1, delta = rep(0, nrow(sigma)),
     type = c("shifted", "Kshirsagar"), ...)
```

where sigma is a correlation matrix.  Now what I am having trouble with is how to sample from a multivariate t-distribution with mean m and covariance matrix S.  Is the following the appropriate syntax?

```
rmvt(1,S,df=n) + m
```

or

```
rmvt(1,R,df=n)*sigma + m
```

where my covariance matrix can be decomposed as S = sigma*R (i.e., R is my correlation matrix).  I am getting different results when I run the two lines of code so that is partially where my confusion stems from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [help file for rmvt](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/bfp/docs/rmvt). There is says that `sigma` is the scale (not correlation) matrix and that the correlation matrix, which is only defined for `df>2` is given by `sigma * df/(df-2)`. Therefore is you have a pre-specified covariance matrix `S` then you should set

```
sigma=S*(D-2)/D
```

where `D` is the degrees of freedom. To generate `n` samples from the multivariate t-distribution with mean `m` and covariance matrix `S` you can either add the mean outside the call to `rmvt`, as you indicated:

```
rmvt(n, sigma=S*(D-2)/D, df=D) + m
```

or by using the `mu` argument:

```
rmvt(n, mu=m, sigma=S*(D-2)/D, df=D)
```

**Edit:** For whatever reason, `rmvt` is not loading properly on my machine so I have to type this first to have the function loaded properly:

```
rmvt <- bfp:::rmvt
```